# Get data with count from different tables

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

I'm using room database and there are two entities named `File` and `Folder`

```
data class File{
   ....
   val folderId: Long? = null,
   ....
}
```

```
data class Folder{
   val id:Long,
   val name:String
}
```

So, I want to get a flow of list of object `Flow<List<FolderDetailWithCount>>`

```
data class FolderDetailWithCount{
    val id:Long?,
    val name:String,
    val count:Long
}
```

which means in which folder(with its name) how many files are stored. (`folderId` of a file is the `id` of folder in which it is located)

So, I don't know how to do this in room and what should be the query for getting this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you need with this custom query:

```
@Query("SELECT fo.id, fo.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FileTable fi WHERE fi.folderId == fo.id) as count FROM FolderTable fo")
suspend fun getFolderDetailWithCountListFlow(): Flow<List< FolderDetailWithCount>>
```

Change **FileTable** with your file table name, and **FolderTable** with your folder table name